# How to find out if a page is opened in embedded browser

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, android-webview, webbrowser-control

Is there a way that can tell my page (the javascript code to be exact) that it is run not in a standalone browser but through embedded one e.g. WebView, Webbrowser control etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect the most common browsers by checking the User agent string and write a javascript/jQuery function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(!browser===Chrome||IE||Safari||FireFox){
   YOUR_CODE
   }
   else{
   DO_NOTHING
   }
});
```

But this is not the best practise.
To achive this if(!browser===Chrome||...)-functionality have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser).

There is everything explained in a comprehensive way.

Comment: The browser I have in mind and need to identify reports as IE7:) `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0E)` so it shows as a browser but in fact it is an embedded control

Comment: Okay, thats intresting.
What is that for a browser you need?

Run the follwing Code snipet in your browser and tell me, what your UserAgent String says

`var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var check = function(r) {
    return r.test(ua);
};`

Edit: Where is this browser embedded? In a nativ application or somewhere else?